# Maximizing a window in a multi-screen environment without hiding/blocking the task bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a post to everyone who has ever asked himself "how do I maximize a window in my multi-screen setup without blocking the task bar".

The problem seems to be that a window that has **MaximizeBox** and **MinimizeBox** set to false and that gets maximized programmatically in a multi-screen environment covers the **entire** screen, not only the **Screen.WorkingArea**.

To maximize a window to the working area only, one needs to utilize the **MaximizeBox** and **MinimizeBox** properties like so:

```
// This code should be placed in the Form's ResizeEnd handler

MaximizeBox = MinimizeBox = true;           // Enable both boxes
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;    // Set to maximized
MaximizeBox = MinimizeBox = false;          // Disable both boxes again
```

Thus, the window will be nicely maximized on the screen and respect the screen's working area (not block the task bar).

Comment: I know it's not really a question ;) but the question behind this.. "How do I do that" pops up so often that I thought it might be useful to post it

Comment: No, it was simply sarcasm.

Comment: And to think that I previously used a WinAPI hack to calculate the area myself... Thanks for this!

Comment: @Basuro you should post your Answer separately in the Answer part were it belongs

Comment: @WiiMaxx will remember your suggestion for next time.

Comment: Not a question but a tip

Comment: Indeed, I just couldn't find the button that says "post tip"..  just wanted to return something useful to the community.. and next time I'll do it in the proper way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set this.MaximumSize to new Size (screen.primaryscreen.bounds.width + screen.secondaryscreen.bounds.width, screen.primaryscreen.bounds.height).

P.S. I wrote this from my phone so I cannot check syntax etc... and also why did you post this as a  'question'?

Comment: Yeah, the question thing was quite stupid... Concerning the maximumsize: That doesn't help with maximizing hiding the task bar

Comment: Oh ok - but that's what I did when my formborderstyle = none and on maximize it covered the task bar, and it workerd.

Comment: Yes, without borders it's no problem since you don't have the border (which should only be visible as a title bar with its buttons in maximized mode) :)

Comment: @Basuro Ah ok sorry - misunderstanding. As a newbie to stackoverflow does this mean I delete my answer?

Comment: no, don't do that... your post may be helpful to people who have a borderless window

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the ResizeEnd event still covered the task bar. So used the Load event instead; no obscured task bar.

Comment: Indeed. But that only maximizes the form once, while it's being loaded. Moving the form to another screen on a multi screen system would not max the form again. That's why I'm using *ResizeEnd*.